# How can I keep track of source code changes with git and box.net?

Tags: software-recommendation, development

I have a school project where I have to make a program(java), therefore I need some way to keep track of the changes I make to the sources; I decided the best way to do this it to create a git repository on my box.net account. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best version control system I have tried is GIT together with [GitHub](https://github.com/).

If you are just a single developer that works on a project then SVN is okayish. However when you start collaborating with other developers or work on multiple computers, then a distributed version control system really shines.

A really good app for working with GIT is [SourceTree (free)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sourcetree-git-hg/id411678673?mt=12).

Comment: I used dropbox instead of GitHUB since I already had all my files there and I'm the only that will be working n this project.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Git. If you want a GUI client take a look at [Gitbox](http://gitboxapp.com/) (paid) or [Github for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) (free)